# Battery has a draw with key off

Tags: electrical, battery, jeep, grand-cherokee

I have a 2000 Grand Cherokee, and I’m having 2.23 Amp draw off the battery when the key is off. Leave the door open 2‒10 min., and the battery is dead or not strong enough to start the vehicle. I go to the drive-ins, leave the radio on with the key on “Aux” position, drains the battery. I bought a new battery, and had it replaced. Running out of ideas as to what could be causing this draw.

Comment: Can you measure power draw with some fuses drawn? Once you find which fuse pulled stops the drain you will have a better idea where to look.

Comment: It is unlikely that the battery could be the cause of parasitic draw by itself, so there was no need to replace it, until the circuits were checked first. Clean the contacts on the terminals, and clean and/or tighten main ground. Then go on and check each circuit as @Hennes suggested: pull one fuse at a time, and see how much it changes the draw to isolate the problem, but keep in mind that some draw is necessary on some circuits (e.g. to keep settings in the radio). If pulling fuses does not help, then the issue is with the wiring before it reaches the fuse box, check your wiring diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Checking some Jeep forums you should see about 50 milliamps of load with every thing off. This accounts for radio presets and various control modules. As others have stated while measuring the load pull the fuses one at a time. Your Jeep should have a fuse box under the dash as well a one under the hood. Grand Cherokees may include some courtesy lights under the dash, sun visors etc that may be staying on.

Comment: I am also guessing that you aren't driving or charging long enough to fully charge the battery. A 2 amp draw shouldn't kill the battery in 10 minutes.